# Find unfrozen brushes in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, freeze, brush

I'm trying to figure out how to find all Brush objects that are not `Freeze="true"` in the Applications resources .

What I've done so far is:

```
var temp = this.FindLogicalChildren<Brush>();
var resourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources;

var resources = GetResources(resourceDictionary);

var brushes = resources.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
     .Where(e => e.Value is Brush).Where(e => !(e.Value as Brush)?.IsFrozen ?? false);
foreach (var entry in brushes)
   ....
```

However this approach has not been able to fit the criteria. Any idea what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this cached website](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:rw-cOaUsa8cJ:csharp.wekeepcoding.com/article/12630938/How%2Bto%2Bfreeze%2Ball%2Bfreezable%2BWPF%2Bobjects%253F%20&cd=26&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nz) that seemed to offer an answer:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
    where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                yield return (T)child;
                }
                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (Freezable item in FindVisualChildren<Freezable>(myWin))
    if( item != null && item.CanFreeze)item.Freeze();
```